# Compare value from database field and check if the same as variable in VB

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g

I'd like to ensure that company names don't be added duplicated
So I would like to check all the records. By removing all kinds of special characters/ Spaces from both values and do compare on both.

the input for example = "Star Treck, LTD"
The database for example has the value "star-treck ltd."

now I want to remove all special chars that were added to the input and remove all from the db field so that I make sure that this company name won't be allowed to be added again

```
' the following is an input given by user to compare with the db records

       dim coname : coname = gs("company name")
                    coname = replace(coname, "_", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, " ", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, "-", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, "(", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, ")", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, "?", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, "&", "")
                    coname = replace(coname, "^", "")
        if Instr(coname, "'") > 0 then
             coname = replace(coname, "'", "''")
        end if
        dim res
        if coname<>"" then
             res="SELECT COID FROM COMPANY WHERE (CONAME='"&coname&"') AND (CLOSEDFLD=0 OR CLOSEDFLD IS NULL)"
             if LEFT(res,4)="ERR:" then
                 msg res
                 exit function
             end if
         end if
```

now how can I remove all the above special chars / make all chars from both for example uppercase to compare

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query with the following

```
res="SELECT COID FROM COMPANY WHERE regexp_replace(UPPER(CONAME),'_| |-|(|)|?|&|^','')='"&coname&"' AND (CLOSEDFLD=0 OR CLOSEDFLD IS NULL)"
```

Comment: This is ripe for SQL injection. If the `coname` input is `' or 1=1 or 'a' = 'a` then it will get every row. Worse, if `coname` is `' or EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM secret_table WHERE type='superuser' AND password_hash = '01234' ) or 'a' = 'a` then you don't just have a problem limited to that one table.

Answer (score 1):

> the input for example = "Star Treck, LTD" The database for example has the value "star-treck ltd."

Your input has `,` while the database has `-` and `.` so you either need to remove the non-alphanumeric characters from both the input and the database value or perform some sort of fuzzy matching.

If you want to replace from both:

```sql
SELECT COID
FROM   COMPANY
WHERE  TRIM( REGEXP_REPLACE( UPPER(CONAME), '[^[:alnum:]]+', ' ' ) )
       =
       TRIM( REGEXP_REPLACE( UPPER(:coname), '[^[:alnum:]]+', ' ' ) )
       AND ( CLOSEDFLD=0 OR CLOSEDFLD IS NULL )
```

*(Note: you should not be using string concatenation to create queries and should, instead, be using bind variables [[example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9832456/1509264)].)*